# Combining fluid flow solver based on lattice Boltzmann method with a mechanical deformation solver based on finite element method

Tags: navier-stokes, solid-mechanics, unstructured-mesh, coupling, lattice-boltzmann-methods

I'm thinking to couple my fluid flow solver based on lattice Boltzmann method with a mechanical deformation solver based on finite element method to take account for solid deformation in my models. In fact, I'm looking for a fluid-structure interaction framework, which its fluid solver was written based on lattice Boltzmann. I didn't find any opensource example by using this coupling idea. Can anyone suggest any opensource software or direction how it is possible to do it?

Comment: This will be relatively complex, because FEM solvers for structures are generally written for unstructured meshes whereas LBM uses a cartesian grid with conformal decomposition. As far as I am aware, there is no such framework that exists. You  might want to look into open source LBM framework such as OpenLB and Palabos and adapt them consequently... I think that the fact that LBM is an explicit method will however greatly hinder your efforts.

Comment: In fact, I have a LBM solver which works on unstructured meshes (not tetrahedralized meshes still it's regularized Cartesian grid but I approximate complex geometries with this fine Cartesian grid).

Comment: Then your LBM solver does not use an unstructured mesh. If you approximate complex geometries using a fine Cartesian grid, you are using a structured cartesian grid to approximate the geometry... This is not an unstructured mesh...